# Matplotlib contourf to represent "hyperbolic" data

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I want to plot a 3-D function z=f(x,y) in contourf fashion, while highlighting some levels where z is constant with black lines and custom labels. The x,y,z data points are contained in a *.csv file which I manipulate with pandas. The function f(x,y) (hence the z-points) have a scaling of type *f(x,y) proprtional to 1/(x*y)*

[This is the result I got with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdVia.png)

As you can see, there's no good scaling results on the colors. I.e. all lines above 99% (which take up the vast majority of the image space) are the same color, whereas I'd like to have a different shade for every "section" (i.e. one shade between 98% and 98.5%, another one between 98.5% and 99%, etc). The colorbar is also weird, and I guess this is due to the wrong scaling in the image, to being with. How do I obtain the wanted result? Hereby the code I'm using as of now (it should be plug-and-play).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True,
    "font.family": "sans-serif",
    "font.sans-serif": "Helvetica",
})
rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{amsmath}' #for \text command

# This custom formatter removes trailing zeros, e.g. "1.0" becomes "1", and
# then adds a percent sign.
def fmt(x):
    s = f"{x:.2f}"
    if s.endswith("0"):
        s = f"{x:.1f}"
        if s.endswith("0"):
            s = f"{x:.0f}"
    return rf"{s} \%" if plt.rcParams["text.usetex"] else f"{s} %"

contour_data = pd.read_csv('MyData.csv', header=None, names=['x','y','z'])

Z = contour_data.pivot_table(index='x', columns='y', values='z', dropna=False).T.values

X_unique = np.sort(contour_data.x.unique())
Y_unique = np.sort(contour_data.y.unique())
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X_unique, Y_unique)

# Initialize plot objects
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 5, 5 # sets plot size
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Define levels in z-axis where we want lines to appear
levels = np.array([98.,98.5,99.,99.5,99.6,99.7,99.8,99.85])

# Generate a color mapping of the levels we've specified
cpf = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z, 
                  len(levels),
                  extend='both',
                  cmap='Reds'
                  )
fig.colorbar(cpf, ticks=levels, orientation='vertical')

# Set all level lines to black
line_colors = ['black' for l in cpf.levels]

# Make plot and customize axes

cp = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 
                levels=levels, 
                colors=line_colors)
ax.clabel(cp, cp.levels, inline=True, fmt=fmt, fontsize=10, colors=line_colors)

ax.set_xlabel(r'$X-\text{axis } [\alpha]$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$Y-\text{axis } [\beta]$')

#plt.savefig('figure_for_stackoverflow.pdf') # uncomment to save vector/high-res version
```

The dataset can be found [here](https://github.com/MattiaIurich/dataset.git)

The only additional requirement I have is that I'd not like to add any other modules to my code if possible. In case the result I'm seeking is impossible to obtain with the imported modules, I'm ready to relax this constraint. In this particular dataset there are no "NaN" elements in Z, but as a general rule I'd like the NaN spots in Z to be white. Thanks for you help!

I tried plotting a surface and highlight constant lines of said surface using a contour/contourf but the result I obtain is not consisted with how my dataset is structured.

Comment: Maybe you can try `ax.contourf(...., colors=plt.cm.Reds(np.linspace(0,1,len(levels)))`, without using `cmap=`?

Comment: @JohanC unfortunately not much changes! The two sectors between 98 and 99 are slightly lighter now, but for 99+ it's all the same color with no changes

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BoundaryNorm`.

[image]

```
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
...
# note that I have extended your levels vector,
# on the bottom and on the top, to cover the full range of z
levels = np.array([z.min(), 98.,98.5,99.,99.5,99.6,99.7,99.8,99.85, z.max()])
cf = plt.contourf(x, y, z,
                  levels=levels,
                  norm=colors.BoundaryNorm(levels,256), cmap='Reds')
ct = plt.contour(x, y, z, levels=levels, colors='k k k k k k w w w w'.split())
cl = plt.clabel(ct)
cb = plt.colorbar(cf)
plt.show()
```

---

*UPDATE*

---

Even better: use `extend='both'` in `contourf` and in `colorbar`,

```
levels = np.array([98.,98.5,99.,99.5,99.6,99.7,99.8,99.85])
cf = plt.contourf(x, y, z,
                  levels=levels,
                  extend='both',
                  cmap='Reds')
ct = plt.contour(x, y, z, levels=levels, colors='k k k k k w w w'.split())
cl = plt.clabel(ct)
cb = plt.colorbar(cf, extend='both')
plt.show()
```

Notice the pointed ends in the Colorbar

[image]

Comment: This solution is very clean! Thank you!